# SQL Union failing

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT TOP 5 
  Notices.Id, 
  NoticeLoc.Notices_Id,
  Loc.Id as Loc_Id, 
  CAST(Notices.Text AS TEXT) as Text, 
  CAST(Notices.Title AS TEXT) as Title, 
  Notices.CDate as RDate 
FROM NoticeLoc 
  JOIN Notices ON NoticeLoc.Notices_Id=Notices.Id JOIN Loc ON NLoc.Loc_Id=Loc.Id WHERE Loc_Id IN (1)

UNION 

SELECT TOP 5 
  Notices.Id, 
  '',
  '', 
  CAST(Notices.Text AS TEXT) as Text, 
  CAST(Notices.Title AS TEXT) as Title, 
  Notices.CDate as RDate 
FROM NoticeC 
  JOIN Notices ON NoticeC.Notices_Id=Notices.Id WHERE C_Id=110 AND CDate BETWEEN '10/01/2011' AND '07/14/2025' ORDER BY RDate desc
```

I am trying to perform a union between 2 result sets using mssql, however I am getting the following error:

> Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The text data type cannot be
>   selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

I have to keep those fields as text fields.

How can I resolve this, cheers.

Comment: Can you format your SQL query? Nobody can read that.

Comment: What is there a reason why you can't use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `TEXT`? You are casting them after all..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UNION by itself is interpreted as using DISTINCT (probably because UNION is trying to mesh the two queries into one DISTINCT list inherently). Use UNION ALL.

Comment: UNION ALL will (possibly) change the actual result set though. i.e. returning all rows, even duplicates, while a simple UNION does not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the type of the data (TEXT). Are you able to change the table to use VARCHAR(MAX) instead? Or drop the TEXT fields from the union? Or perhaps just cast the fields to VARCHAR(MAX) in your query?

VARCHAR(MAX) is functionally the same as text (unlimited length, not stored in the row, etc.).

Comment: in MSSQL there is no such thing as varchar, only nvarchar. Which causes huge problems with php.

Comment: support for varchar has been removed since sql server 2008 onwards.

Comment: @bobo2000 thats not true at all. Even in SQL Server 2012 it is fully supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: Would you have a source to verify that varchar is not supported? We have SQl 2008 at work, and it still has both varchar and nvarchar.

Comment: In my experience casting or converting the fields to varchar(max) in the query will lead to huge performance issues when it comes to check distinct values.

Comment: But leaving them out changes the result set. If two rows were identical except for the text/varchar(max) fields, then they would be combined in the result.